# How can I limit the amount of messages SendMail will recieve in a single incoming connection?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

Is there a way to limit how many messages can be received by SendMail in a given SMTP session?

I have a SendMail server and an upstream application server is trying to send dozens (potentially hundreds) of messages to it in a single SMTP session (`ehlo`... `mail from`... `rcpt to`... `data`... `rset`... `mail from`... etc).  This is causing resource strain on the box since the traffic isn't effectively load balanced.  I'd like to implement a policy to have sendmail only allow up to X number of messages in a given SMTP session after which it will require the remote host to reconnect again.

I noticed that there's a `confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE` option but that seems to protect more against multiple connections occurring at once - not a single connection sending a bunch of emails.

Comment: Are you looking only for sendmail.cf (non milter based) solution?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Correct. I want to achieve this with a vanilla SendMail install - no additional milters or third-party products.  Is this possible?

Comment: I do not remember easy way.